# Struggling to convert a number to base 64 in Python without strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode, number-theory

So I am trying to program (in Python 3 without strings) this cool project that I found.

Return the 6-character string representation of the 36-bit number n as a base-64 number in reverse order where the order of the 64 numerals is:

`0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-+`

For example,

```
encode(0) → '000000'
encode(9876543210) → 'gR1iC9'
encode(68719476735) → '++++++'
```

What I have so far is:

```
def encode(n):
  SYM = {'0': 0,
         '1': 1,
         '2': 2,
         '3': 3,
         '4': 4,
         '5': 5,
         '6': 6,
         '7': 7,
         '8': 8,
         '9': 9,
         'A': 10,
         'B': 11,
         'C': 12,
         'D': 13,
         'E': 14,
         'F': 15,
         'G': 16,
         'H': 17,
         'I': 18,
         'J': 19,
         'K': 20,
         'L': 21,
         'M': 22,
         'N': 23,
         'O': 24,
         'P': 25,
         'Q': 26,
         'R': 27,
         'S': 28,
         'T': 29,
         'U': 30,
         'V': 31,
         'W': 32,
         'X': 33,
         'Y': 34,
         'Z': 35,
         'a': 36,
         'b': 37,
         'c': 38,
         'd': 39,
         'e': 40,
         'f': 41,
         'g': 42,
         'h': 43,
         'i': 44,
         'j': 45,
         'k': 46,
         'l': 47,
         'm': 48,
         'n': 49,
         'o': 50,
         'p': 51,
         'q': 52,
         'r': 53,
         's': 54,
         't': 55,
         'u': 56,
         'v': 57,
         'w': 58,
         'x': 59,
         'y': 60,
         'z': 61,
         '-': 62,
         '+': 63,}
```

But now I am not sure what to do next. I do not want to use strings and concatenation etc, I would like to do this using modulus and the standard number theory + `for`/`while`/`else` methods.

My thoughts were to define

```
r1 = n % 63
r2 = r1 % 63
r3 = r2 % 63
r4 = r3 % 63
r5 = r4 % 63
r6 = r5 % 63
```

But I'm not sure what to do from there.

For example, how should I convert n to base 64? At the end, to reverse the digits after I have found the new representation, I am thinking that I will just mod each power of 10 to isolate each individual digit and then concatenate them in reverse order. However, I'm not sure how to program this in Python, since I'm relatively new to the language. All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Examine what `//` does.

Comment: What does your second sample of code do?

Comment: Test that with `n` equal to 100.

Comment: Now by hand figure out what they should be.

Comment: Convert 123 into decimal. The *long* way.

Comment: No, it's just a number.

Comment: The **long** way.

Comment: Right. *Now.* Which part of the second blurb divides?

Comment: Maybe you got confused because `n%64 == n & 63`...

Comment: BTW, that `SYM` would be handy if you were _decoding_, but since you're encoding, you can just index into a string. Incidentally, I'm not impressed on them using `+` and `-` as digits.

Comment: That's getting close, except you need `while`, not `for`, and think about the order of the operations. Work through the algorithm on paper and see what happens. It may be easier if you do that with a different base, like 10, or 16.

Comment: `SYM['K']` evaluates to 20, but `SYM[20]` raises `KeyError`. If you're going to use a dict, then you need the inverse of SYM, a dict with integer keys and string values

Comment: Do you know how to convert a decimal number to binary or hex by hand? The same algorithm applies here.

Comment: The values in that dictionary are supposed to be strings, but without the quotes Python sees them as variable names. Like I said, you need `20: 'K',` Etc, not `'20': K,`. Another way to do the conversion is with an `if... elif` block. Anyway, I think you've suffered enough. ;) I'll post some code shortly.

Comment: Well done! We got there in the end. ;)

Comment: It's probably a good idea if you tidy this up a bit by deleting some of those obsolete comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that does what you want. The `get_digit` function uses a bunch of `if... elif` tests to convert an integer `d` in 0 <= d < 64 into its corresponding character number, and then uses the standard `chr` function to convert that number to the actual character. The `encode` function does the actual remainder calculations, calling `get_digit` to do the character conversion, and saving the results into the `out` list. We append that list with `'0'` characters to make its length 6.

```
def get_digit(d):
    ''' Convert a base 64 digit to the desired character '''
    if 0 <= d <= 9:
        # 0 - 9
        c = 48 + d
    elif 10 <= d <= 35:
        # A - Z
        c = 55 + d
    elif 36 <= d <= 61:
        # a - z
        c = 61 + d
    elif d == 62:
        # -
        c = 45
    elif d == 63:
        # +
        c = 43
    else:
        # We should never get here
        raise ValueError('Invalid digit for base 64: ' + str(d)) 
    return chr(c)

# Test `digit`
print(''.join([get_digit(d) for d in range(64)]))

def encode(n):
    ''' Convert integer n to base 64 '''
    out = []
    while n:
        n, r = n // 64, n % 64
        out.append(get_digit(r))
    while len(out) < 6:
        out.append('0')
    return ''.join(out)

# Test `encode`
for i in (0, 9876543210, 68719476735):
    print(i, encode(i))
```

**output**

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-+
0 000000
9876543210 gR1iC9
68719476735 ++++++
```

---

Since we're working with a base that's a power of 2, an alternative to

```
n, r = n // 64, n % 64
```

is to use bitwise operations

```
n, r = n >> 64, n & 63
```

which are slightly faster, but I guess that doesn't make much difference here, and the previous code is more readable. OTOH, it can be useful to understand why the bitwise version produces the correct result.

Comment: I can't upvote because I don't have enough rep, but thank you so much.

Comment: I plugged it in and it works ;) thanks again. Now I am going to spend the next few hours understanding it!

Comment: So now I am trying to write the inverse of this program - one that decodes. I realize that I should change `chr` to `ord,` but what else?

Comment: I suggest you first work on the inverse of `get_digit`. You can do stuff like `if 'A' <= c <= 'Z': d = ord(c) - 55` . If you need help with this new program, please ask a fresh question. In your new question you should say that it's a follow-on question from this one and include [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739875/converting-a-number-to-base-64-in-python).

Comment: Done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751441/converting-from-a-string-to-a-number