# Converting from a string to a number in base-64

Tags: python, string, radix, number-theory

So, I am trying to write a program to decode 6-character base-64 numbers.

Here is the problem statement:

> Return the 36-bit number represented as a base-64 number in reverse order by the 6-character string s where the order of the 64 numerals is: 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-+

i.e.

> decode('000000') → 0
>
> decode('gR1iC9') → 9876543210
>
> decode('++++++') → 68719476735

I would like to do this WITHOUT strings.

The easiest way to do this would be to create the inverse of the following function:

```
def get_digit(d):
    ''' Convert a base 64 digit to the desired character '''
    if 0 <= d <= 9:
        # 0 - 9
        c = 48 + d
    elif 10 <= d <= 35:
        # A - Z
        c = 55 + d
    elif 36 <= d <= 61:
        # a - z
        c = 61 + d
    elif d == 62:
        # -
        c = 45
    elif d == 63:
        # +
        c = 43
    else:
        # We should never get here
        raise ValueError('Invalid digit for base 64: ' + str(d)) 
    return chr(c)

# Test `digit`
print(''.join([get_digit(d) for d in range(64)]))

def encode(n):
    ''' Convert integer n to base 64 '''
    out = []
    while n:
        n, r = n // 64, n % 64
        out.append(get_digit(r))
    while len(out) < 6:
        out.append('0')
    return ''.join(out)

# Test `encode`
for i in (0, 9876543210, 68719476735):
    print(i, encode(i))
```

**Output**

```
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-+
0 000000
9876543210 gR1iC9
68719476735 ++++++
```

Which is actually from PM 2Ring on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739875/converting-a-number-to-base-64-in-python/46740374#46740374) page.

How do I write the inverse of this program?

A start:

The inverse of get_digits as above is below:

```
def inv_get_digit(c):

    if 0 <= c <= 9:
        d = ord(c) - 48
    elif 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        d = ord(c) - 55
    elif 'a' <= c <= 'z'
        d = ord(c) - 61
    elif c == '+':
        d = 63
    elif c == '-':
        d = 62
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid Input' + str(c))
    return d


def decode(n):

    out = []
    while n:
        n, r= n % 10, n ** (6-len(str))
        out.append(get_digit(r))
    while len(out) < 10:
        out.append('0')
    return ''.join(out)
```

Comment: Please try to write some code yourself. As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739875/converting-a-number-to-base-64-in-python/46740374#comment80448645_46740374), the first step is to invert `get_digit`, and I gave you a hint how to do that.

Comment: I have edited my post to reflect your comment. I didn't post the new code in the comments because the format gets skewed. Unless it's better that way?

Comment: No, never post multi-line Python code in comments because the indentation gets lost. But anyway, your code belongs in the body of the question itself, comments are just to help you clarify & improve your question.

Comment: You `inv_get_digit` looks good, although I haven't tested it, and you need to fix the indentation. Now try to write `decode`, and if you get stuck post the code for that, and clearly explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Okay, I wrote (an attempt) at decode. My problems are with the line `n, r= n % 10, n ** (6-len(str))` which I know is wrong, but I don't know what to replace it with. And a question, what does the '' in `''.join(out)` mean?

Comment: For your join question, use a python prompt to take a look at expressions like `', '.join([x for x in 'abc'])` and you'll soon see. For `n, r`, you want to cut down `n` by the base, which isn't 10. And you want `r` to be the remainder.

Comment: The `''` in `''.join(out)` says what separator to use to join the items in `out`. So that expression says to use an empty string as the separator. Try this: `print('-'.join('hello'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a program that combines [my old code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739875/converting-a-number-to-base-64-in-python/46740374#46740374) with some new code to perform the inverse operations.

You have a syntax error in your `inv_get_digit` function: you left the colon off the end of an `elif` line. And there's no need to do `str(c)`, since `c` is already a string.

I'm afraid that your `decode` function doesn't make much sense. It's supposed to take a string as input and return an integer. Please see a working version below.

```
def get_digit(d):
    ''' Convert a base 64 digit to the desired character '''
    if 0 <= d <= 9:
        # 0 - 9
        c = 48 + d
    elif 10 <= d <= 35:
        # A - Z
        c = 55 + d
    elif 36 <= d <= 61:
        # a - z
        c = 61 + d
    elif d == 62:
        # -
        c = 45
    elif d == 63:
        # +
        c = 43
    else:
        # We should never get here
        raise ValueError('Invalid digit for base 64: ' + str(d)) 
    return chr(c)

print('Testing get_digit') 
digits = ''.join([get_digit(d) for d in range(64)])
print(digits)

def inv_get_digit(c):
    if '0' <= c <= '9':
        d = ord(c) - 48
    elif 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        d = ord(c) - 55
    elif 'a' <= c <= 'z':
        d = ord(c) - 61
    elif c == '-':
        d = 62
    elif c == '+':
        d = 63
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid input: ' + c)
    return d

print('\nTesting inv_get_digit') 
nums = [inv_get_digit(c) for c in digits]
print(nums == list(range(64)))

def encode(n):
    ''' Convert integer n to base 64 '''
    out = []
    while n:
        n, r = n // 64, n % 64
        out.append(get_digit(r))
    while len(out) < 6:
        out.append('0')
    return ''.join(out)

print('\nTesting encode')
numdata = (0, 9876543210, 68719476735)
strdata = []
for i in numdata:
    s = encode(i)
    print(i, s)
    strdata.append(s)

def decode(s):
    out = []
    n = 0
    for c in reversed(s):
        d = inv_get_digit(c)
        n = 64 * n + d
    return n

print('\nTesting decode')
for s, oldn in zip(strdata, numdata):
    n = decode(s)
    print(s, n, n == oldn)
```

**output**

```
Testing get_digit
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-+

Testing inv_get_digit
True

Testing encode
0 000000
9876543210 gR1iC9
68719476735 ++++++

Testing decode
000000 0 True
gR1iC9 9876543210 True
++++++ 68719476735 True
```

Comment: Ahh once again, thank you. One simple question, why must we use 's' as the argument?

Comment: @JustAMathematician No worries. We could call the argument of `decode` anything we like. I just used `s` because it's a mnemonic for "string", and I was too lazy to come up with a more meaningful name. ;) Similarly, I've used `c` for char, and `d` for digit. Generally it's a Good Idea to use longer more descriptive names, but it can be ok to use short names when it's obvious what's going on. Of course, what's obvious to the writer may not always be obvious to the reader. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to do this WITHOUT strings.

First, you need to clarify what this means.  What you offer as a working encoder uses these strings:

```
out.append('0')
return ''.join(out)
```

And the accepted solution adds these strings:

```
digits = ''.join([get_digit(d) for d in range(64)])
if '0' <= c <= '9':
elif 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
elif 'a' <= c <= 'z':
elif c == '-':
elif c == '+':
```

Do you mean that *single* character strings are acceptable but multiple character strings are not?  Or do you mean you don't want to use a `str` as a data structure and wish to minimize string operations?

I feel your solution, and the accepted solution which builds upon it, are doing too many operations at encode and decode time.  I recommend a little bit of work up front to build data structures and less effort when working through the data:

```
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

BASE10_TO_BASE64 = list(digits + ascii_uppercase + ascii_lowercase + '-' + '+')

BASE64_TO_BASE10 = {base64: base10 for base10, base64 in enumerate(BASE10_TO_BASE64)}

ZEROS = ['0'] * 6

def encode(number):
    ''' Convert base 10 int to reversed base 64 str '''

    characters = []

    while number:
        number, remainder = divmod(number, 64)
        characters.append(BASE10_TO_BASE64[remainder])

    return ''.join(characters + ZEROS[:max(len(ZEROS) - len(characters), 0)])

def decode(string):
    ''' Convert reversed base 64 str to base 10 int '''

    number = 0

    for character in string[::-1]:
        digit = BASE64_TO_BASE10[character]
        number = 64 * number + digit

    return number

if __name__ == "__main__":

    NUMBERS = (4096, 9876543210, 68719476735)
    strings = []

    print("Encode:")
    for number in NUMBERS:
        string = encode(number)
        print(number, string)
        strings.append(string)

    print("\nDecode:")
    for string in strings:
        number = decode(string)
        print(string, number)
```

Encoding to *reversed* base 64 numbers and zero padding complicate the program but add nothing.  We usually expect '100' to represent the square of the base, but not here.

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Encode:
4096 001000
9876543210 gR1iC9
68719476735 ++++++

Decode:
001000 4096
gR1iC9 9876543210
++++++ 68719476735
>
```